# MSP is marked not applicable when it's installed via Wix Bundle

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, bundle

I am using WiX bundle to apply multiple MSPs.

A MSP (hotfix.msp) is target to SP1 of product A. I created the hotfix.msp with "ProductValidateFlags" equal 0x00000922.

When I double click the MSP file directly, the hotfix.msp can be applied properly on product A with SP1 installed.

However, I created a WiX bundle package which include hotfix.msp, after the bundle is installed, the hotfix.msp isn't applied.

The log information:

> [0118:02C4][2018-05-30T14:56:28]i106: Calculating patch applicability for target product code: {B8136533-98DA-40CD-BCB0-AC798AEB71B8}, context: Machine
>
> [0118:02C4][2018-05-30T14:56:28]i101: Detected package: hotfix, state: Absent, cached: None
>
> ...
>
> [0608:0904][2018-05-30T14:40:01]i200: Plan begin, 1 packages, action: Install
>
> [0608:0904][2018-05-30T14:40:01]i201: Planned package: hotfix, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
>
> [0608:0904][2018-05-30T14:40:01]i000: Running plan complete BA function

Source code to include the MspPackage in WiX bundle:

> ```
>  <MspPackage Id="hotfix" DisplayName="Sample Hotfix" SourceFile="$(env.hotfix)" Permanent="no" Cache="yes" Vital="yes">
>   </MspPackage>
> ```

btw, the hotfix can be applied normally if I change the ProductValidateFlags to 0x902.

Thanks
Jeremy

Comment: That's not the important log line with respect to installing the package or not. We need the Plan log lines to see what it plans to do with the package.

Comment: Hi @BrianSutherland, I attached the plan log. The execute action is None.

Comment: If this is an MspPackage element, please show the details.

Comment: Hi @PhilDW, I added the source code to involve MSP package. I went through all attributes that described in the document. It seems not a attribute can control this. I think WiX bundle also use the ProductValidateFlags to validate if the msp is applicable. But i am confused by the different behavior with install MSP directly.

Comment: When you install the MSP manually, does it show UI? And the WiX install has no UI? I'm wondering if there is a patch command line (or other setting) being applied in the UI sequence which therefore won't be set in a silent patch install.

Comment: WiX bundle package detect the applicable product at the beginning before real install. I don't know what's the logic of WiX bundle detecting.